# Python call function passed as argument on object

Tags: python, oop

Is there a way to pass a custom function as a parameter in a class method and have an object call that function? I'm writing a custom logger and would like to do something like this

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('name')
        ...

    def write(self, writeFunction, message):
        self.logger.writeFunction(message)  # something like this
        self.logger.call(writeFunction, args=[message])  # or something like this in other languages
```

where `writeFunction` is something like `info()`, `debug()`, etc (I know the example above isn't allowed in python)

Trying to avoid having to pass a log level as a parameter and doing a bunch of if statements to determine which logging function to call

UPDATE: I found that the loggers have a method `log()` that does what I'm looking for, but what about other objects in general?

Comment: You can just call it like `writeFunction()`

Comment: writeFunction is a member function of self.logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely pass a callable as a parameter.  It would look more like this (adding type annotations to help clarify the usage):

```
    def write(self, write_function: Callable[[str], None], message: str):
        write_function(message)
```

Then to call this function you'd do:

```
    write(self.logger.info, "my message")
```

The `write` function would just call whatever function you passed as the parameter (in this case `self.logger.info`) with the given `message`.  Adding type annotations is useful here because it's easy to get confused about what types are expected in which context, but mypy will help you keep it all straight -- in this case the type annotation tells us that whatever function we pass to `write` will be called with a single `str` argument.